# Dev server for Java, like VS has for .NET?

Tags: java, jsp, ide, webdev.webserver

I am on a Java learning spree recently, however I am normally a .NET developer. (So please forgive my newbie questions.)

In .Net I can develop ASP.Net pages without using IIS, as it has a watered down web server (Cassini, I think it's called).

Does Java or a Java IDE have something similar so I can write and test JSP and Java Servlets without the need of a full-blown app server (Tomcat etc.)?

Also if there is one, does it work on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) actually isn't a fullblown appserver. It's *just* a servlet container (i.e. implementing only web component of the (indeed huge) Java EE API) It's only around [6MB](http://mirror.its.uidaho.edu/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.24.zip) big. [Glassfish](http://glassfish.dev.java.net), [JBossAS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/), [Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/appserver/weblogic/enterprise-edition.html) and [Websphere](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/) as being *full* Java EE API implementations may be called as "fullblown appservers".

You can also consider [Eclipse Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). It has a small footprint (download is only [2.2MB](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/dist/jetty-distribution-7.0.1.v20091125.zip)) and is useable as an embedded server and even runnable from a [plain vanilla Java class](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

As to IDE's, both Tomcat and Jetty are by default supported in "[Eclipse for Java **EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php)". You can easily integrate them in *Servers* view and then just associate your web project with it. [Here's a nice video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs) how to get started with servlet development with Eclipse and Tomcat.

As to working on Windows, Java is platform independent. You just need to have a platform-compatible JRE installed. Then any Java software will be able to run on the particular platform. Sun has a [JRE](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jre-6u18-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) for Windows --which is by the way also included in the [JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp), if you already have one.

Comment: Tomcat is full-blown enough if you're not using EJBs.  If you're a Spring user, Tomcat is sufficient.

Comment: It's certainly sufficient for just developing with only JSP/Servlet API.

Comment: Using tomcat from within Eclipse or Netbeans is relatively simple and works just fine for developing JSP/Servlets

Comment: Actually, JBoss has an embedded API as well (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossEmbeddedAS), and so does GlassFish v3 (http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_glassfish_v3_in_unit). And JBoss, WebLogic, GlassFish v3 (and more) are all supported in Eclipse by default. At least, as much as Jetty i.e. after downloading the appropriate adapter.

Comment: Good to know about those embedded API's. As to Eclipse, yes that's correct. They can all be handled by Eclipse. My answer was actually more targeted on "simple" servletcontainers :)

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine and has my +1 anyway, it's the nitpicker in me that was speaking :)

Answer (score 4):

In the Java world the usual way to develop JSP based applications is to have a web container like Tomcat inside the IDE, and there are many ways to do it.

The easiest way to get started is to use Netbeans with a bundled web container - download the "Java" one from http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html and install it.

After starting Netbeans 6.8, "File -> New project", choose "Java Web" to the left, and "Web application" to the right, and "Next".  "Next". "Next". "Finish".

The editor now opens on "index.jsp" in a new project.  Select "Debug -> Debug Main Project" and after a while a browser opens showing "index.jsp".

Switch back to Netbeans.  Insert this line

```
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

just before the `</body>` end tag, and save with Ctrl-S  (or "File -> Save").

Switch back to the browser.  Reload the page.  See the date shown.  Repeat :)

That's it.

Comment: I agree, NetBeans is the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jetty http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

Jetty is an Open Source HTTP Servlet Server written in 100% Java. It is designed to be light weight, high performance, embeddable, extensible and flexible, thus making it an ideal platform for serving dynamic HTTP requests from any Java application.

EDIT: corrected link.

Comment: I had problems with the link.  This one worked for me: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

Comment: Jetty is since a while hosted by Eclipse. See my answer for correct link.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up your ant scripts to hot deploy to a local tomcat instance.  That's the closest thing I can think of to the .NET development environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) can embed a dev version of Tomcat, and most other IDEs offer a dev server too, I should think.

But also I should also point out that obtaining & setting up Tomcat is quite a bit simpler than setting up IIS.  Just download a zip file and unzip -- poof!  you're done!

Answer (score 0):

When I was playing with JSP a while back I used  [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) which has a [Web & Java EE](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/)-installer, that

> Provides tools for developing Java SE,
>   Java EE, and web applications. This
>   download option also includes the
>   GlassFish V2 UR2 application server
>   and Apache Tomcat software.